# jQuery color animate not syncing across multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble syncing a color change animation using jQuery. For some reason, the font color inside a button element only changes when every other color change has finished processing. Here is the code:

```
$(".jumbotron-fluid, .btn").animate({
    backgroundColor: colors[seed]["background"]
});
$(".container").animate({
    backgroundColor: colors[seed]["container"]
});
$("p, blockquote footer, .btn, a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active, a").animate({
    color: colors[seed]["font"]
});
```

Here is a link to a CodePen that shows this project in action: http://codepen.io/christianflorez/full/OWdYRm/

When clicking on the "Get a new quote" button, every time the font color in the button changes to white, it doesn't change in sync with the rest of the DOM. Anyone know why this might be happening? I've tried testing the code across multiple browsers and the same issue appears. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Javascript is not multi-threaded. Only one process at a time. Your jQuery animations will only fire after the previous one is completed when scripted in the format you have. To get around this, you can put the animation functionality all inside a single handler and the animations will kick off once the single function is called.

Comment: @Korgrue, javascript is indeed not multi-threaded but that doesn't mean jQuery animations can't proceed in parallel. Each animation occurs in many separate event threads, allowing multiple animations to interleave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `queue`parameter of `animate` is set `true` as default. As you animate `.btn` twice, the second animation is fired after the end of first. Change `queue` to `false` for the first `.btn` animate. [codepen link](http://codepen.io/devrafalko/pen/vgPBLL)

```
$(".jumbotron-fluid, .btn").animate({
   backgroundColor: colors[seed]["background"]
 },{queue:false}
);
$(".container").animate({
   backgroundColor: colors[seed]["container"]
  }
);
$("p, blockquote footer, .btn, a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active, a").animate({
   color: colors[seed]["font"]
  }
);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much for the solution and explanation!